# Rewrite rule is only working when there is dot, i.e when file has some extension

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting, web-config

Here is my rewrite rule:

```
 <rule name="Rewrite blog" stopProcessing="true">
        
         <match url="^blog/(.*)" /> 
    
        <action type="Rewrite" url="https://blog.mydomain.hr/{R:1}" />
    </rule>
```

It is not working. I am 100% sure that url is matched because if I don't change anything besides of changing "Rewrite" to "Redirect" then redirection is successfull.

Also, I am 100% sure that rewrite module is installed on IIS and enabled for site because other rewrite rules are working. This is example of rewrite rule that actually works:

```
<rule name="Rewrite  images" stopProcessing="true">
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
    <match url="^pictures/(.*)$" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://ws.mydomain.com/IMG-SERVICE/ImagesService.svc/{R:1}" />
  </rule>
```

Only difference I noticed is that this second rule has extension in it (it redirects images ending in .jpg for example)

If I go to /blog/en/whatever.someLettersAfterDot or /blog/en/whatever.whateverextension than it successfully rewrites but not when /blog/en or /blog/someUrlWithoutExtension is used.

My rewrite rule that doesn't work is first in list and has stopProcessing=true. Nothing changes if I make it as only rule so I am sure it doesn't interfere with some other rules.

Comment: The easiest way is to use [failed request tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules) to view the detailed request process, and you will find the problem.